# NSPredicate to query parent and child

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a data model setup with three entities, Course, Student, TestScores.

They are linked in too-many relationships like this:

```
Course <---->> Student <---->> TestScores
```

So a Course would have several Students, who in turn could have several TestScores (or no test scores)

The Course entity has a Name attribute. TestScores is a simple entity which just contains a testScore int attribute.

I want to be able to get an array of Students who have at least one textScore of 100, ordered by Course name. Is this possible with NSPredicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could have your predicate as

```
ANY testScores.score == 100
```

Then put it all together in a fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestForEntityNamed:@"Student"];
req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY testScores.score == 100"];
req.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"course.name" ascending:YES]];
```